# how to make the jquery function load before one ajax function finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I fire one event before the previous function completed its function?

I have the following AJAX code :

```
var BrainyFilter = {
    //...
    init: function (opts) {},
    changeTotalNumbers: function (data) {
        jQuery(BrainyFilter.filterFormId).find('.bf-count').remove();
        jQuery(BrainyFilter.filterFormId).find('option span').remove();
        jQuery(BrainyFilter.filterFormId).find('select').removeAttr('disabled');
        jQuery('.bf-attr-filter').not('#bf-price-container').find('input, option')
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
            .parents('.bf-attr-filter')
            .addClass('bf-disabled');

        if (data && data.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                jQuery('.bf-attr-' + data[i].id + ' .bf-attr-val').each(function (ii, v) {
                    if (jQuery(v).text() == data[i].val) {
                        var parent = jQuery(v).parents('.bf-attr-filter').eq(0);
                        var isOption = jQuery(v).prop('tagName') == 'OPTION';
                        var selected = false;
                        if (isOption) {
                            jQuery(v).removeAttr('disabled');
                            selected = jQuery(v)[0].selected;
                        } else {
                            parent.find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
                            selected = parent.find('input')[0].checked;
                        }
                        parent.removeClass('bf-disabled');
                        if (!selected) {
                            if (!isOption) {
                                parent.find('.bf-cell').last().append('<span class="bf-count">' + data[i].c + '</span>');
                            } else {
                                jQuery(v).append('<span> (' + data[i].c + ')</span>');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            jQuery('.bf-attr-filter input[type=checkbox]').filter(':checked')
                .parents('.bf-attr-block').find('.bf-count').each(function (i, v) {
                var t = '+' + jQuery(v).text();
                jQuery(v).text(t);
            });
            // since opencart standard filters use logical OR, all the filter groups
            // should have '+' if any filter was selected
            if (jQuery('.bf-opencart-filters input[type=checkbox]:checked').size()) {
                jQuery('.bf-opencart-filters .bf-count').each(function (i, v) {
                    var t = '+' + jQuery(v).text().replace('+', '');
                    jQuery(v).text(t);
                });
            }
        }

        // disable select box if it hasn't any active option
        jQuery(BrainyFilter.filterFormId).find('select').each(function (i, v) {
            if (jQuery(v).find('option').not('.bf-default,[disabled]').size() == 0) {
                jQuery(v).attr('disabled', 'true');
            }
        });
    },
    //...
} // close the BrainyFilter
```

I also have another jQuery file running to get the bf-count value using `$('.bf-count').text()`.
When the page load, the `bf-count` value is empty. Since the code above inject the `bf-count`, I will need to wait until it finishes the `for` loop in order to get the `bf-count` value.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Can you slim down your code example? It's very hard to understand what function you want to execute and when..

Comment: Hi, I think i will just insert the external sorting code in the line of code that call the ajax in ajax file.. Manage to sort it out.Thanks for your suggestion anyway..

Comment: I can't see any async calls here? what do you mean by ajax?

Answer (score 0):

without knowing how the second js file is loaded, I can only give you a guesstimate suggestion.

If you want to run the second js file code *after* the page is fully loaded, you can wrap the code in:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    //your code here. runs after the page is fully loaded 
});
```

jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

"The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object."